# How do I use the same variable in 12 different button events?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a double variable "total" to be used in different buttons but I'm not sure how to do this.  Below is a what I will be doing in each of the different buttons:

```
private void btnItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblItemPrice.Text = string.Format("£{0:0.00}", btnItem2.Tag);

    lstTill.Items.Add(btnItem2.Text + "\t" + (string.Format(btnItem2.Tag.ToString())));

    this.lstTill.TopIndex = this.lstTill.Items.Count - 1;

    total = total+ Convert.ToDouble(btnItem2.Tag);
    lblTotalPrice.Text = "£ " + Convert.ToString(lblItemPrice);
}
```

Where do I create the variable "total" so it can be used in the different buttons?

Comment: Suggestion: Read about [Scopes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Is the code in all your event handlers the same except for the source of the click event (`btnItem2` in your example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the total variable at class level not in the event level.

```
double total = 0; 

private void btnItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        lblItemPrice.Text = string.Format("£{0:0.00}", btnItem2.Tag);

        lstTill.Items.Add(btnItem2.Text + "\t" + (string.Format(btnItem2.Tag.ToString())));

        this.lstTill.TopIndex = this.lstTill.Items.Count - 1;

        total = total+ Convert.ToDouble(btnItem2.Tag);
        lblTotalPrice.Text = "£ " + Convert.ToString(lblItemPrice);
    }
```

Comment: knew it was something very simple! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need `total` to be a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). That is, declared inside the class, but outside any method.

So:

```
double total = 0.0;
```